# Google OAuth works on localhost but not on production server

Tags: next.js, oauth-2.0, vercel, supabase

I have set up Google OAuth using Superbase, and it's working fine on my localhost:3000, but not on my production site which is hosted on Vercel.

The problem is like this on my production server.

- I log in using my Gmail account
- Get redirected to my site with a ?code attached to the URL.
- A new cookie is saved to my website.
- There is no Auth session.

You can see my URL Configuration here.
[image]

Did I do something wrong? or do I need to change things somewhere else in Google Cloud for example?

One thing to note is that I'm using NextJS 13.

Comment: I've setup a project using Next 13 with Supabase and Google auth that I've deployed to Vercel without any issues. Can you share some code as just seeing your dashboard config area isn't enough to help with this issue. A minimal reproducible repository would help greatly. You can view my test project here https://github.com/silentworks/safari-vercel-test

Comment: I appreciate your response.
It turned out that there was an additional period before the environment variable that was used on Vercel.

I took so long to discover because there were no errors displayed anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, it was a typo in the environment variable I used on Vercel.
I know, embarrassing.